# how to increase Stack Size of a running program in C

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, posix

I am trying to identify any way if we can increase the stack size of my running program after getting SIGSEGV. I know we can increase the size of stack by ulimit -c but, that did not solve this problem. Because my process is already dead. I want to handle this situation where my process will not get killed even after segfault. setrlimit() is one way which can be used for exceed stack size statically. But I don't want to block more memory than I need.

Comment: I need to take care if program gets stack over flow while running. Program should be able to handle it and increase the size of stack _dynamically_ at run time.

Answer (score 3):

Under Linux, setting a higher limit for the stack size does not commit this memory to your process.   The memory will be paged in as required.

The default stack size in quite large already. You should run under the debugger or produce a core upon SIGSEGV to analyze what is really going on.  You might have a very deep recursion, or an inordinate amount of local variable space, possibly via VLAs allocated by mistake.  Increasing the stack space may hide the problem for a while, but it is not a reliable solution.

Comment: I can't agree any more. I'm sure that there is some 'bugs' in the code, show me the code.

Comment: I mean I agree with you very much. sorry for my poor English. :)

Answer (score 1):

A recent OS will not automatically reserve the memory for the stack, but just add pages as required. The ulimit is just an upper bound you allow it to use up. So increasing the stack size statically should be no problem and exactly what you want.

Comment: I need to take care if program gets stack over flow while running. Program should be able to handle it and increase the size of stack dynamically at run time.

Comment: Ok. So you will have to edit that program anyway. Sorry, can't help with that. Problem is that the segfault will trash the stack frame, so silent recovery would be impossible. I'm actually not sure this is even possible, as that might break security. Only option I can think of is to have a watchdog called each time a stack frame is created (profiling-stubs might help here) and check for an internal threshold. But that would be quite a performance killer. You better rethink why/if you actually nee that much stack space. Perhaps you will get along better with malloc()

Comment: Just to state it clear (again): The stack _is_ increased dynamically. That is done by the Linux kernel. No memory is allocated in advance, but only as required. If your program wants to know when a page is committed, then your program is very likely hacky at best (debugging/profiling tools excepted).